# Joomla template main menu position

Tags: css, joomla

I'm having a problem with removing the bullet point's from my menu, and changing it from a list view, to a vertical view. The template should look how any menu should look like. I will provide pictures below, any help is good, thanks!

---

[image: My Problem]

---

[image: Backend]

---

[image: How it should look like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Joomla, the field menu class suffix is used to specify a piece of text - without spaces - which will be appended to the class of the menu block.

For example, if you use the  layout type for a meny, there will be a

```
<div class="moduletable">
```

If you add a suffix of "_mysite", this will change to

```
<div class="moduletable_mysite">
```

So you can't use this field to specify custom CSS, this needs to go into your template's css code. You can only specify a suffix for a class here.